# Regex matchin string that containts at least one specific character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create an expression that matches anything between two whitespaces that does contain at least one `-` but have no f** idea how to do that.

Trying things like `(?<=\s)[A-Z0-9(\-)+]+(?=\s)` don't work at all...

Has anybody a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
(?<=\s)\S*-\S*(?=\s)
```

You might not even need the look ahead/behind:

```
\S*-\S*
```

may work just fine